# Using field alias in calculated fields

Tags: oracle

I have 2 case statements in my select query :-

```
   case 
      when substr(tariff_name,1,1) = 'S' then 
        case 
          when t.utility = 'Water' then '107.96'
          when t.utility = 'Foam' then '104.96'
        end
      when substr(tariff_name,1,1) = 'J' then 
        case 
          when t.utility = 'Water' then '90.88'
          when t.utility = 'Foam' then '70.07'     
        end
   end AS Annual_SC_Cost, 
   case 
      when substr(tariff_name,1,1) = 'S' then 
        case 
          when t.utility = 'Water' then eac * 0.11821
          when t.utility = 'Foam' then eac * 0.02707
        end
      when substr(tariff_name,1,1) = 'J' then 
        case 
          when t.utility = 'Water' then eac * 0.1338
          when t.utility = 'Foam' then eac * 0.03055 
        end
   end AS Annual_Cons_Cost
```

What I'd like to do is have another select that is essentially like this :

```
        case 
          when t.tlength = 12 then (Annual_SC_Cost * Annual_Cons_Cost) * 1
          when t.tlength = 24 then (Annual_SC_Cost * Annual_Cons_Cost) * 2
        end
```

Is this possible, and if not, is there an alternative approach that keeps the calculation to a single SQL query?

Comment: Yes and no. You can't use aliases defined in a SELECT clause as identifiers in other calculations in the same SELECT clause. The common solutions are: (1) repeat the code everywhere it's needed - it's more efficient in execution, but a pain in the butt to maintain; or (2) use a subquery - outer query structure. Define the aliases in the subquery and use them in the outer query to build the additional computations. Since Oracle 11.1, the `with` clause is used often to organize the code in this manner - it makes it a lot easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Using string as numbers is always a bad idea, better use number simply like `107.96` or `90.88`. Otherwise your query will fail if another user has German NLS-Environment, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the very specific computation you show, assuming you only need the result of the final computation (and you don't need the intermediate results, created in the first code snippet), you could rearrange the code so that each computation is done just once. You don't even need aliases for the intermediate results. Like this:

```
...
,
case   <calculation that produces annual_sc_cost>   end
*
case   <calculation that produces annual_cons_cost> end
*
case  t.length  when 12 then 1  when 24 then 2 end
```

Other notes: `tariff_name like 'S%'` is equivalent to `substr(tariff_name, 1, 1,) = 'S'` and generally more efficient. Also, `case` expressions where you compare something to fixed values can be written more concisely as I demonstrated with `t.length` above. (Read about "simple" vs. "searched" case expressions - google for these phrases; the concept is pretty basic, not hard to understand and to use).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
   case 
      when substr(tariff_name,1,1) = 'S' then 
        case 
          when t.utility = 'Water' then '107.96'
          when t.utility = 'Foam' then '104.96'
        end
      when substr(tariff_name,1,1) = 'J' then 
        case 
          when t.utility = 'Water' then '90.88'
          when t.utility = 'Foam' then '70.07'     
        end
   end AS Annual_SC_Cost, 
   case 
      when substr(tariff_name,1,1) = 'S' then 
        case 
          when t.utility = 'Water' then eac * 0.11821
          when t.utility = 'Foam' then eac * 0.02707
        end
      when substr(tariff_name,1,1) = 'J' then 
        case 
          when t.utility = 'Water' then eac * 0.1338
          when t.utility = 'Foam' then eac * 0.03055 
        end
   end AS Annual_Cons_Cost
```

Use first query as a substring and join your table again.

Answer (score 0):

you can use your query as inline view and do operation on respective alias fields like below-

```
SELECT CASE
          WHEN t.tlength = 12 THEN (Annual_SC_Cost * Annual_Cons_Cost) * 1
          WHEN t.tlength = 24 THEN (Annual_SC_Cost * Annual_Cons_Cost) * 2
       END final_output
  FROM (SELECT CASE
                  WHEN SUBSTR (tariff_name, 1, 1) = 'S'
                  THEN
                     CASE
                        WHEN t.utility = 'Water' THEN '107.96'
                        WHEN t.utility = 'Foam' THEN '104.96'
                     END
                  WHEN SUBSTR (tariff_name, 1, 1) = 'J'
                  THEN
                     CASE
                        WHEN t.utility = 'Water' THEN '90.88'
                        WHEN t.utility = 'Foam' THEN '70.07'
                     END
               END
                  AS Annual_SC_Cost,
               CASE
                  WHEN SUBSTR (tariff_name, 1, 1) = 'S'
                  THEN
                     CASE
                        WHEN t.utility = 'Water' THEN eac * 0.11821
                        WHEN t.utility = 'Foam' THEN eac * 0.02707
                     END
                  WHEN SUBSTR (tariff_name, 1, 1) = 'J'
                  THEN
                     CASE
                        WHEN t.utility = 'Water' THEN eac * 0.1338
                        WHEN t.utility = 'Foam' THEN eac * 0.03055
                     END
               END
                  AS Annual_Cons_Cost
          FROM t)
```